# Проблема с текстом в Qt

Tags: qt5, mingw

Есть программа по работе с текстом(технические данные ниже) в некоторых словах появляются баги наложение букв или  очень большая удаленность их друг от друга в слове. Просьба смотреть фото.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Использование моноширных шрифтов не решает проблему на 100%

Используется `Qt5.9.9`, `MinGW 5.3`
При изменении геометрии или перемещении по горизонтали элемента графики, содержащего текст, интервал между буквами не постоянен и колеблется (это хорошо видно на записи экрана).

Класс элемента текста унаследован от `QGraphicsItem`, отрисовка реализована через `QPainter::drawText`:

```
void QPainter::drawText(const QRectF &rectangle, int flags, const QString &text, QRectF *boundingRect = nullptr)
```

следующим образом:

```
painter->drawText(rect(), Qt::TextWordWrap, text4show_);
```

Попытка применить `QTextDocument::drawContents` к явному успеху не привела, но уменьшила быстродействие.

**Дополнение от [@Ingwar Smith](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/407277/)**

Это не ответ Виктору, но уточнение его вопроса и замечания по комментариям к нему (я программист-исполнитель):

1. Без `Qt::TextWordWrap` проблема остается (проверено) и, разумеется, переноса строк не происходит при отрисовке текста внутри потомка `QGraphicsItem`
2. Вызов отрисовки текста:

painter->drawText(rect(), flags, text4show_);

При этом flags (тип int32_t) может быть результатом побитового ИЛИ между флагами:

```
Qt::AlignLeft
Qt::AlignRight
Qt::AlignHCenter
Qt::AlignJustify
Qt::AlignTop
Qt::AlignBottom
Qt::AlignVCenter
Qt::AlignCenter
Qt::TextDontClip
Qt::TextSingleLine
Qt::TextExpandTabs
Qt::TextShowMnemonic
Qt::TextWordWrap
Qt::TextIncludeTrailingSpaces
```

-- за исключением того, что `Qt::TextWordWrap` и `Qt::TextSingleLine` не могут объединяться

3. Наконец, по поводу кода.
   Схема наследования такова (потомок->родитель):
   TextItem -> Item -> QGraphicsItem

-- From Item header:

```
class Item : public QGraphicsItem { / ... / };
```

-- From TextItem header:

```
class TextItem : public Item
{
public:
    TextItem(QGraphicsItem *parent = nullptr);

    // ...

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget = nullptr) override;

    // ...

private:
    // ...
    QString text4show_;
    Qt::Alignment alignment_;
    bool multiline_;
};
```

-- From TextItem cpp-file:

```
void TextItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    painter->save();
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::TextAntialiasing, true);
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
    // ...

    int flags = alignment_;
    if (!multiline_)
    {
        flags |= Qt::TextSingleLine;
    }
    else
    {
        flags |= Qt::TextWordWrap;
    }

    painter->drawText(rect(), flags, text4show_);

    painter->restore();
    Item::paint(painter, option, widget); // этот вызов приведен ниже
}
```

-- From Item cpp-file:

```
void Item::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem * /*option*/, QWidget * /*widget*/)
{
    if (select_ && rect_.isValid()) { // в общем, это рисует прямоугольник границ элемента (Item'а)
        painter->save();
        painter->setPen(QPen(QColor(79, 128, 255), lead_ ? 0.6 : 0.3));
        painter->drawRect(rect_);
        painter->restore();
    }
}
```

Comment: Без `Qt::TextWordWrap` проблема остается?

Comment: Тут бы не помешал [минимальный код, воспроизводящий проблему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Если просто в drawText засунуть lorem ipsum - проблема остается?

Comment: Воспроизвести не удается .Подобного отображения удалось добиться только если посреди слова есть перевод строки(`"dev\nices"`) и установлен флаг `Qt::TextSingleLine`. Проверьте содержимое текста.

Comment: @MaximTimakov, просьба вам: приведите ваш пример кода, в котором "подобного отображения удалось добиться только если посреди слова есть перевод строки...", пожалуйста.

Comment: @Victor, [ловите](https://gist.github.com/max-dark/b0a7424e9402548fd95a1a5f8f7bb0c2#file-gfxtextitem-cxx)

Comment: @MaximTimakov-  спасибо огромное!) Так как вы написали работает но у нас там есть часть кода и в целом не работает в программе как нужно... А вы бы на платной основе могли бы посмотореть проконсультировать нас?